# Controllers, Models, and updating select properties

Tags: laravel, forms

I've gone through quite a few tutorials, and I'm starting to get there with Laravel, however, one thing I've somehow missed in these tutorials/failed to spot, is how to accomplish "selective updating", apologies if that's the wrong wording, however this is my issue.

I have the **user** model, this contains multiple custom fields on top of the auth fields added by Laravel, the custom fields are:

- ConsiderForAccommodation
- Attending

I currently have a form in a view that allows the user to set choose whether they would like to be considered for accommodation, this works as follows:

**User Model**

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'considerForAccommodation'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

**User Controller**

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    // Update the given user
    $user = auth()->user();

    // If the value is null then it's false.
    $user->ConsiderForAccommodation = $request->input('ConsiderForAccommodation') != null;

    $user->save();

    return redirect('/accommodation');
}
```

**Accommodation View (form)**

```
@section('content')
        <h1>Accomodation</h1>
        <p>This is the accomodation page.</p>

        {!! Form::open(['action' => ['UserController@update', Auth::id()], 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
                <div class="form-group">
                        {{Form::label('ConsiderForAccommodation', 'Consider Me For Accommodation')}}
                        {{Form::checkbox('ConsiderForAccommodation', null, Auth::user()->ConsiderForAccommodation)}}
                </div>
                {!! Form::token() !!}
                {{Form::hidden('_method', 'PUT')}}
                {{Form::submit('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary'])}}
        {!! Form::close() !!}
@endsection
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@index');
Route::get('/accommodation', 'PagesController@accommodation');
Route::get('/registry', 'PagesController@registry');
Route::get('/rsvp', 'PagesController@rsvp');
Route::get('/schedule', 'PagesController@schedule');
Route::get('/travel', 'PagesController@travel');

Route::resource('user', 'UserController');

Auth::routes();
```

As I mentioned, this imlementation works as intended. Now, the issue is I have another seperate form (within a different view), that I would like to contain a form that **only** updates the "Attending" value against the model. How do I handle this in Laravel?

Do I have to create a seperate controller for each property I wish to update seperatly from the others, or am I looking at this wrong entirely and there's an easy way of doing it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possibilities how to solve this problem. One of them is to create one route that also has a parameter

```
Route::put('/users/set-parameter/{param}', 'UserController@setParameter');
```

Then in controller you can set different parameters in single method:

```
public function setParameter(Request $request, string $param)
{
    $user = auth()->user();
    $user->{$param} = $request->input($param) != null;
    $user->save();
    return redirect('/accommodation');
}
```

Keep in mind that sometimes it is not the best way to handle that. There are pros and cons as almost always.

Comment: This sounds exactly like what I'm after, I'll give it a whirl now.